# How to check for tap in monogame?

Tags: android, monogame

I want to check that `Rectangle` was tapped. This mehod does the job and it works almost how I want:

```
private bool CheckRectangleTouch(Rectangle target)
{
    var touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
    if (touchCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var touch in touchCollection)
        {
            if (target.Contains(touch.Position))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Problem I have is that after I've tapped rectangle it keeps returning `true` until I release it (it can register 10-30 times for one tap) and I want it to return `true` just once - for the first touch.

I've tried this (replace code inside `foreach`):

```
            var isFirstTouch = !touch.TryGetPreviousLocation(out _);
            if (target.Contains(touch.Position) && isFirstTouch)
            {
                return true;
            }
```

And this (bad one, I don't really want it to register after release):

```
            if (target.Contains(touch.Position) && touch.State == TouchLocationState.Released)
            {
                return true;
            }
```

But nothing is does it. Either logic is not consistent or doesn't work at all.

So how do I check for tap?

Update: this works but it's very hacky, has delay and gives me random phantom taps:

```
    try
    {
        var tap = TouchPanel.ReadGesture(); // falls each time when no input
        return tap.GestureType == GestureType.Tap && target.Contains(tap.Position);
    }
    catch { }

    return false;
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used the `TouchPanel` stuff but I had a thought. Are you calling `TouchPanel.GetState` more than once during a single `Update` frame?

Comment: Yes, twice. One for screen tap (main game input) and one for pause button tap

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea generally. Try only calling it once per frame and see if that helps.

Comment: ok, but how whould it help? It will still register touch if finger is still on the screen

Comment: Mate, it was just a thought. I don't know if it will help with your problem or not. In my experience calling `GetState` more than once in a frame can be the cause of bugs like the one you're describing. Try it or don't, it's just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I did just in case, thanks for notice

Comment: Not related to your question but do not use for-each when using monogame, only use a simple for. for-each creates garbage which burdens the gc.

Comment: @Fredrik thanks, will look into it. Can you reference an article about that?

Comment: @IvanMaslov I have seen a lot of bug issue about GC, and for-each has come up sometimes, however I was able to find this article now when I searched where they mention for-each vs for: https://kosmonautblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/13/tips-tricks-for-monogamexna-developers/

Comment: I see, but in my case I enumerate TouchCollection which consists of structs wich do not take up space in heap, but are stored in stack. So I think I'm good here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:
I have singleton to hold my game state (many different props updated as needed). I added to it:

```
public TouchCollection TouchCollection { get; set; }
```

Prop to hold TouchPanel.GetState result. I fill it in Games Update method once per frame, as @craftworkgames suggested:

```
State.TouchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
```

Also I added this prop to my game state:

```
public bool TouchActive { get; set; }
```

And this is the method to check for rectangle tap. It returns true only for the first contact in tap:

```
    private bool CheckRectangleTap(Rectangle target)
    {
        if (State.TouchCollection.Count == 0)
        { // if no input
            return State.TouchActive = false;
        }

        var targetTouched = false;
        foreach (var touch in State.TouchCollection)
        {
            if (target.Contains(touch.Position))
            {
                targetTouched = true;
            }
        }

        if (targetTouched && !State.TouchActive)
        { // if target is touched and it's first contact
            return State.TouchActive = true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

It doesn't seem ideal but it works for my case.